# Find last 10 business days of the current month for schedule

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a couple of scenarios

1. Scheduler should compare the current day is with in the last 10 business days of the current month then it should schedule to run current day with 11AM CST.
   (E-g) current day : 18th July 2017 (with in last 10 business days) should run and reschedule at 19th July 2017 11.AM CST
2. IF Last business day(30th or 31st) after runs the scheduler should reschedule it to next month.
   (E-g )current day : 31th July 2017 (with in last 10 business days) should run and reschedule at 18th Aug2017 11.AM CST

Can any one help to derive the logic in oracle 11g scheduler?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question and the scenario's. Please elaborate with better input-output examples.

Comment: You should define what is a business day. And please show what you have tried till now.

Comment: You description is incomplete as February only has 28 or 29 days. Are your business days Monday through Friday? @Nitish is correct, you need to define what a business day is.